# Accessing spring user in service layer and controllers - any update for Spring 3.2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to access the current logged in user I am doing it like this (from a static method)

```
public static User getCurrentUser() {

final Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof User) {
  return (User) principal;
  }
}
```

or injecting and casting like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Foo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getFoo(@PathVariable Long id, Principal principal) {
        User user = (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
..
```

Where user implements userdetails, both seem a bit lame is there a better way in Spring 3.2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it has something new in `spring 3.2` for that purpose. Have you thought about using a custom annotation?

Something like this :

The controller with the custom annotation :

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo/bar", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String fooAction(@LoggedUser User user) {
        System.out.print.println(user.getName());
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

The LoggedUser annotation :

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RententionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface LoggedUser {}
```

The WebArgumentResolver :

```
public class LoggedUserWebArgumentResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {

    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, NativeWebRequest webRequest) {
        Annotation[] annotations = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotations();

        if (methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(User.class)) {
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                if (LoggedUser.class.isInstance(annotation)) {
                    Principal principal = webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
                    return (User)((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
                }
            }
        }
        return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

Beans configuration :

```
<bean id="loggedUserResolver" class="com.package.LoggedUserWebArgumentResolver" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="customArgumentResolver" ref="loggedUserResolver" />
</bean>
```

Comment: to be honest that seems like a lot of work when I already have the static method

Comment: This is what I do and it works great. As for it being a lot of work, I would counter that calling a static method to get the current user sounds like a lot of work compared to annotating a controller argument. Also this approach makes your controller more testable.

Comment: @NimChimpsky it is a little more work to set up, but the benefit is that once you've done so you can a) Reuse it and b) its much easier to test. . . . I usually to the same thing, but with an Aspect.

Comment: @JasperBlues I guess spring don't wire up their own as everyone implements their own custom user class ? I just add a user to securitycontext for my tests btw, and the static method is accessible from all layers not just controllers.

Comment: @NimChimpsky coolio, if that's working for you. . . Re annotation - it would still be a handy feature of SpringSecurity, there's at least an interface there that could be passed in. . . might file a ticket with them.

Comment: Spring Security 3.2 provides this exact functionality out of the box: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal

Answer (score 0):

I created a method much like your static, but put it in a new spring bean and inject that bean into the controllers (or objects at other layers) in which I need to get information about the user.  That way I avoid the difficulties in testing code that depends on a static and all the code messing with the SecurityContext is nicely encapsulated into my bean (as you have in your static)